# How do I convert between the transaction ID formats in fn_dblog() and sys.dm_tran_database_transactions?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, database-internals

`fn_dblog()` shows transaction IDs in this format:

```
0000:00049d43
```

And `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` shows transaction IDs in this format:

```
9811233
```

I believe the above examples show the same transaction ID in different formats.

Is there a way to convert between the two formats? Or are these actually two different entities -- and in that case, is there a way of matching up `fn_dblog()` with the transaction-related DMVs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe that the `[Transaction ID]` column of `sys.fn_dblog()` is the transaction ID you are looking for. The transaction id in that result set that matches the `transaction_id` column of `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` is `[Xact ID]`.

Try the following:

**Find a Transaction ID**

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
WHERE  database_id = DB_ID();
```

**Get that Transaction's details from the Log**

```
DECLARE @TransactionID NVARCHAR(50);

SELECT @TransactionID = [Transaction ID]
FROM   sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE  [Xact ID] = 10450416; -- some [transaction_id] from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions

--SELECT @TransactionID;

SELECT *
FROM   sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE  [Transaction ID] = @TransactionID;
```

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully this helps someone else who has the same misconception that I had.